# poll functions always returns zero on POLLOUT

Tags: c, sockets

I am writting a thread which needs to handle 5 different TCP port (read and write).
For this I create 5 sockects like this (only PORT is different):

```
sock_tcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP);

/* Allow socket to reuse address */
sockopt = 1;
setsockopt(sock_tcp, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &sockopt, sizeof(sockopt));

/* bind socket to an address */
memset(&addr_tcp, 0, sizeof(addr_tcp));
addr_tcp.sin_family = AF_INET; /* Address family */
addr_tcp.sin_port = htons(10001); /* Port number */
addr_tcp.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* IPv4 address */
if (bind(sock_tcp, (struct sockaddr *) &addr_tcp, sizeof(addr_tcp))) {
        pr_err("tcp socket failed");
    }
```

In thread I fill pollfd array and use poll function:

```
/* Create array for poll function */
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    /* Set socket in passive mode */
    listen(sock[i].sockfd, 1);
    /* Set socket initial only in receiving mode with events 
       which will trigger the socket */
    pfd[i].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI | POLLOUT;
    /* Add socket in a structuret */
    pfd[i].fd = sock[i].sockfd;
}
```

later in code is written:

```
ret = poll(pfd, 5, 0);
```

With this I am able to receive data from all 5 sockets, and it is working. Functions is returning if socket received data.
Problem occurs when I try to send data.
I try to add in events POLLOUT and wait that poll function give me that socket is ready for sending. This never occurs and poll always send for POLLOUT zero???

Does someone have any idea what should I do?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sockets in question are TCP listening sockets, they will never be ready for writing.  You can only `accept()` from one of these sockets, which will return you a new socket for the accepted connection.

Also, you're not setting up a non-blocking socket correctly.  Assuming Linux, it's done as follows:

```
int flag;
if ((flag = fcntl(sock_tcp, F_GETFL)) == -1) {
    perror("Error getting socket descriptor flags");
}
flag |= O_NONBLOCK;
if (fcntl(sock_tcp, F_SETFL, fdflag) == -1) {
    perror("Error setting non-blocking option");
}
```

Comment: From pieces of code which I send you can see that socket is set as non-block.
But I never receive positive answer from poll function regarding POLLOUT.
I also tried to use accept function regardles on answer from poll function thus getting active socket, but I receive error:
sock_active = accept(pfd[i].fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
An if I try direct to use socket for sending:
ret = sendto(pfd[i].fd, msg, msg->message.header.msglen, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, addrlen);
I also receive error???

Comment: Looks like I missed a few things.  I've updated my answer.  Also, what error are you getting when you try to `accept`?

Comment: This is my first time that I use TCP, but non-block worked as is with UDP socket. I will try with yours solution.
On accept function I received error -1 and if I continue to sendto function I receive error "SIGPIPE broken pipe". That means that socket is not active and connected.
Problem is if I use connect function, because then socket is active and then I cant switch socket back to listen and use socket for receive.

Comment: If you get back -1 from `accept`, you need to call `perror` to print the exact error message, otherwise you don't know what happened.  Also, you can't use `sendto` on TCP sockets -- it's for UDP only.  And the only function you can call on a listening socket is `accept`.

Comment: You were right about accept, I totally miss understand principle of TCP server. Also I used program which was just sending data to my application thus accept didn`t worked (there were no client).
Now I made test client using Microsoft example and now accept works. Server on Linux can now do accept.
I try to modify code according to you regarding non-block, but still my socket is block and get stuck on read.
Any advice how can I fix this and make my socket non-block.?
p.s I next message I will give you my code since message is to long!

Comment: Here it is
'sock_tcp5 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP);
sockopt = 1;
setsockopt(sock_tcp5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &sockopt, sizeof(sockopt));
memset(&addr_tcp5, 0, sizeof(addr_tcp5));
addr_tcp5.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr_tcp5.sin_port = htons(10000);
addr_tcp5.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
flag = 0;
if ((flag = fcntl(sock_tcp5, F_GETFL)) == -1) {
 perror("Err");
}
flag |= O_NONBLOCK;
if (fcntl(sock_tcp5, F_SETFL, flag) == -1) {
perror("Err");
}
if (bind(sock_tcp5, (struct sockaddr *) &addr_tcp5, sizeof(addr_tcp5))) {
 perror("Err");
}'

Comment: Please post the code in your question along with a description of the problems you are still having.

Comment: Hello, just to wrote that I found what was the root of my problem. Socket can work only as server or as client, but it cant do both. I try to do both and it didn`t worked (one socket cant be called in function listen and also in function accept).